# Degrees/sec to axis-angle

Tags: c, math, physics, trigonometry, axis

I have a sheet of Gyroscope readings in degrees/sec (X, Y, Z). I need to convert it to Axis-Angle format (X, Y, Z, THETA) in C.
Here is what I came up with:

```
void gyroToAxisAngle(double gyro[3], double axis_angle[4]) {
    double gyroRad[3];
    // Convert gyro values from degrees per second to radians per second
    gyroRad[0] = gyro[0] * M_PI / 180.0;
    gyroRad[1] = gyro[1] * M_PI / 180.0;
    gyroRad[2] = gyro[2] * M_PI / 180.0;

    // Calculate the angular velocity magnitude
    double gyroMagnitude = sqrt(gyroRad[0] * gyroRad[0] + gyroRad[1] * gyroRad[1] + gyroRad[2] * gyroRad[2]);

    // Calculate the axis of rotation
    axis_angle[0] = gyroRad[0] / gyroMagnitude;
    axis_angle[1] = gyroRad[1] / gyroMagnitude;
    axis_angle[2] = gyroRad[2] / gyroMagnitude;

    // Calculate the rotation angle (theta)
    axis_angle[3] = gyroMagnitude;
}
```

Let's take these gyro values as an example `{-22.767, 145.174, -47.1}` and the resulting values were `XYZ: (-0.147539, 0.940781, -0.305225)`, `Theta: 2.693255`.

Could anyone confirm if I'm converting correctly, or if there is a more accurate way to convert? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at: [Maths - Conversion Euler to Axis-Angle](https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/eulerToAngle/index.htm). Take note of the **Issues** section!

Comment: I also recommend the following wiki articles: [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) and [Axis–angle representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation).

Comment: If you read the proposed articles, you'll realize that there is a distinction in how to interpret the angles (order of rotation).

Comment: Any minor rounding errors in the calculation will probably be negligable compared to the uncertainty of the measured values.

Comment: Technically, I guess `sqrt(fma(gyroRad[0], gyroRad[0], fma(gyroRad[1], gyroRad[1], gyroRad[2] * gyroRad[2])));` should be slightly more accurate or no worse than the original. I also tried `hypot(hypot(gyroRad[0], gyroRad[1]), gyroRad[2]);` but that was slightly less accurate than the original (probably because it does two square root operations).

Comment: One more issue to consider carefully: what happens when the inputs are 0? You'll have divide by zero problems. You need to have a "default angle of rotation" when inputs are 0, or to check parameters before passing them to the function.

Comment: @Surge, Also, if all 3 inputs are less than `sqrt(DBL_TRUE_MIN)`, we get divide by zero issues.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica If the readings are coming from real hardware, then the code probably does not need to worry about stupidly large values or stupidly small, non-zero values.

Comment: @IanAbbott Agree that `mag == 0.0` is the most probable edge case, yet even with that, a vector may be -0.0.  What is most challenging (and interesting) is forming a sensible answer for all `double` angles.

Comment: Thank you for the responses guys! A few things I wanna mention: firstly, I only have a handful of values that I need to convert, none of which will be 0 or extremely small/large.

Comment: Second, I want to use these values in Webots simulator. Basically, I am trying to visualize accident data coming from Gyro (when a car gets hit and rotates), and Webots vehicle takes axis-angle values, meanwhile I only have Euler angles from the gyro. @IanAbbott any confirmation on whether I'm converting correctly?

Comment: *"any confirmation on whether I'm converting correctly?"* The approach agrees with the following source, at least: https://www.euclideanspace.com/physics/kinematics/angularvelocity/#axisangle

Comment: @wiswasi Important info like "none of which will be 0 or extremely small/large." deserves to be in the edited post.

Answer (score 0):

> if there is a more accurate way to convert?

**Divide by 0.0 [@
Surge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77240919/degrees-sec-to-axis-angle/77241318#comment136178847_77240919)**

With all zero inputs (or even all inputs less than `sqrt(DBL_TRUE_MIN)` in magnitude), code incurs divide by 0.0.

In that case, some alternate code is needed.

```
if (gyroMagnitude == 0.0) {
  // TDB code needed to handle all tiny cases.
} else {
  // The usual
}
```

**Overflow**

Although not likely with OP's values, code may want to better handle overflow.  Could use TBD alternate code in that case or wider types.

**For a few bits more**

Yes, use wider math (when `long double` is wider than `double`) and `FLT_EVAL_METHOD < 2`.

Perhaps not the few bits of improvement OP is seeking, yet here it is:

```
// long double constant - degrees to radians
#defined D2R (3.1415926535897932384626433832795L / 180)

void gyroToAxisAngle(const double gyro[3], double axis_angle[4]) {
    // Convert gyro values from degrees per second to radians per second
    long double gr0 = gyro[0] * D2R;
    long double gr1 = gyro[1] * D2R;
    long double gr2 = gyro[2] * D2R;

    // Calculate the angular velocity magnitude
    long double gyroMagnitude = sqrtl(gr0*gr0 + gr1*gr1 + gr2*gr2);

    // Calculate the axis of rotation
    axis_angle[0] = (double) (gr0 / gyroMagnitude);
    axis_angle[1] = (double) (gr1 / gyroMagnitude);
    axis_angle[2] = (double) (gr2 / gyroMagnitude);

    // Calculate the rotation angle (theta)
    axis_angle[3] = (double) gyroMagnitude;
}
```

I estimate OP's results will be up to about 1 or 2 [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) better.

---

Print with `"%.17g"` (or `"%a"`) rather than `"%f"` for assessing accuracy.

---

[Edit]

Since `axis_angle[0 to 2]` are all *normalized* angles and so have lost their degree/radian units, there is no need to convert first to radians.  That unneeded conversion loses a little accuracy and is work that can be avoided.  Only `axis_angle[3]` needs a degrees to radians conversion.

```
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>

// Rather than  a * pi / 180, insure only 1 operation. 
#define DEGS2RADS(a) ((a) * (3.1415926535897932384626433832795/180))

void gyroToAxisAngle(const double gyro[3], double axis_angle[4]) {
  // Conversion to radians is not needed as code is forming a normalized vector.
  // Conversion slightly increases accuracy. 

  // Calculate the angular velocity magnitude
  double gyroMagnitude = sqrt(
      gyro[0] * gyro[0] + gyro[1] * gyro[1] + gyro[2] * gyro[2]);

  // See below code to handle extremes, 
  // or just handle the tiny value case with your own code
  if (gyroMagnitude == 0.0) {
    // TBD Code to handle tiny or the zero case.
    return;
  }

  axis_angle[0] = gyro[0] / gyroMagnitude;
  axis_angle[1] = gyro[1] / gyroMagnitude;
  axis_angle[2] = gyro[2] / gyroMagnitude;
  axis_angle[3] = DEGS2RADS(gyroMagnitude);
}
```

To handle extremes:

```
  // If all the gyroRad are small, scale them up, centered about exponent = 0 
  #define SCALE (-DBL_MIN_EXP*3/4)
  if (gyroMagnitude < DBL_MIN) {
    // Scaled up versions of gyroRad_scaled[]
    double g_x[3];
    g_x[0] = scalbn(gyro[0], SCALE);
    g_x[1] = scalbn(gyro[1], SCALE);
    g_x[2] = scalbn(gyro[2], SCALE);
    gyroMagnitude = sqrt(g_x[0] * g_x[0] + g_x[1] * g_x[1] + g_x[2] * g_x[2]);
    // All gryo[] are zeros. 
    if (gyroMagnitude == 0.0) {
      // Make all same magnitude
      double mag = 1.0 / sqrt(3.0);
      axis_angle[0] = axis_angle[1] = axis_angle[2] = axis_angle[3] = 0.0;
      return;
    }
    gyroMagnitude = scalbn(gyroMagnitude, -SCALE);
  } else if (gyroMagnitude > DBL_MAX) {
    // TBD Code
    return;
  }
```

Comment: Note: no confirmation if OP is generally converting correctly,

Comment: `gyro[]` contains angular velocities, not angles, so range reduction by `fmod` is not appropriate.

Comment: @IanAbbott Agree range reduction not appropriate for angular velocities.  Answer amended.

Comment: Your special case for `if (gyroMagnitude == 0.0)` makes the vector too large. It is supposed to be a unit vector. I don't suppose the direction matters too much, but if you want to keep the `copysign` stuff to get a choice of 8 directions, replacing `1.0` with the result of `sqrt(3)/3` would do fine.

Comment: Also with your special case, shouldn't it be assigning to `axis_angle[x]`, using the sign from `gyroRad[x]` rather than the way you have it the other way round?

Comment: @IanAbbott 1) Yes, need unit vector.  Will ponder.  2) Yes, that was a wrong assignment.